# On button pressed go to different view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, theos

I have this button and I want when clicked to go to a different view controller.  How do I do this?

```
- (void)buttonPressed:(UIButton *)button {
    NSLog(@"Button Pressed");
}
```

NOTE: I am using theos.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a Storyboard to set up your views, you can ctrl-click and drag from the UIButton to the new view. This will set up a Segue for you which you can customise further.

Comment: Im actually using theos but nobody seems to really know abt theos....Theres no drag and drop features everything is manually coded so i just need a code

Answer (score 0):

In main.storyboard go right click the button, select a segue, drag to the view controller you want it to take you to.

Comment: Well theres no theos and still even in xcode things can be done programatically and its driving me crazy that theres no theos tutorials

Comment: I searched for a while in Xcode looking for the code that creating a segue would make but I couldn't find it. I did find this tutorial though, hope it will help: https://sites.google.com/site/theostutorials/chapter-5-ui-buttons/lesson-1-code-a-button

Answer (score 0):

You can present a `UIViewController` programatically in several ways.

Are you working for iOS8? use `showViewController:sender:` or `showDetailViewController:sender:` and `presentViewController` (if you want it modally)

Are you working for iOS7? use `pushViewController`, but be aware this method is **deprecated**

If you want to know more about how to use this methods you should read about [UIViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006926-CH3-SW96) and [UINavigationController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006934-CH3-SW13) at the documentation, hera are the methods I named explained in both Objective-C and Swift

Comment: This sounds exactly on the lines of what i need im on ios8 and all i have in my app folder right now is main.m Beta.mm RootViewController.h And RootViewController.mm